# Python: using psycopg3 to connect to specific schema in database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg3

this is my first time asking a question, cause usually i'm able to find an answer in older threads.
ANYWAY, i'm developing a software (in Python) to analyze certain kind of errors inside specific tables in a database (in PostgreSQL). The structure is like this:

```
DATABASE
├── schema1
│   └── some_table
│   └── another_talbe
│   └── just_table
│   └── supreme_table
├── schema2
    └── (guess what, other tables)
```

So, using psycopg, i was able to connect to DATABASE, but i have to work only on the first schema, so it's pretty annoying to write every query with something like "schema1.some_table". Is there something i missed to connect directly to a specific schema?

First thing i tried was using a dotted dbname for psycopg (like dbname="DATABASE.schema1") but it didnt work.
Then i tried looking at the documentation, in search of a parameter that could help me, but didnt find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely not in `psycopg3` itself, but see [the documentation on the schema search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH); you can probably just call

```
con.execute("SET SEARCH_PATH to schema1")
```

as the first thing you do with your connection.

Comment: That's it! That's what i've been missing! Thanks a lot, also for the docs :)